# React Native app has low performance while fetching data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I have a react native app that gets slow/freeze while fetching data from realtime db.
This is only on android devices, on IOs the app works fine.

for example, by using the performance monitor in my physical device I get:

- UI: 59 fps
- 79 DROPEDD
- 3 Stuters fo far
- JS: -2.1 fps
  I get the data in the App.js as the following code, which it is inside an useEffect with an empty dependency array:

```js
async function fetchData() {
      try {  
        const [
          postFetched,
          categoriesFetched,
          assetsFetched,
        ] = await Promise.all([getAllPosts(), getCategories(), getAssets()]);

        const email = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@email');
        //Alert.alert(`whats uid ? ${email}`);
        if (email) {
          const userFetched = await searchUserByEmail(email);
          setUser(Object.values(userFetched.val())[0]);
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        const t2 = performance.now();
        //Alert.alert(`time ${(t2 - t1) / 1000} seg`);
        return {postFetched, categoriesFetched, assetsFetched};
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.toString());
      }
    }

    fetchData()
      .then((data) => {
        const {postFetched, categoriesFetched, assetsFetched} = data;
        if (postFetched.exists()) {
          setPosts(
            orderBy(
              toArray(postFetched.val()),
              ['isTop', 'created'],
              ['desc', 'desc'],
            ),
          );
          //setLoading(false);
        }
        if (categoriesFetched.exists()) {
          setCategories(toArray(categoriesFetched.val()));
        }
        if (assetsFetched.exists()) {
          setAssetsFirebase(assetsFetched.val());
          // SplashScreenNative.hide();
        }
        // SplashScreenNative.hide();
        /*if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }*/
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Toast.show({
          type: 'error',
          text1: 'error ' + error.toString(),
        });
        console.log('error', error);
      });
listenPostsChange();  // -> this also inside the same use effect
```

the listenPostChange function:

```js
  const listenPostsChange = () => {
    listenPosts((data) => {
      data.exists() &&
        setPosts(
          orderBy(toArray(data.val()), ['isTop', 'created'], ['desc', 'desc']),
        );
    });
  };
```

the firebase methods are defined in a separate js file for each reference:

post.js

```js
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
const PostsRef = database().ref('/posts');
export const listenPosts = (callbackFunction) => {
  return PostsRef.on('value', callbackFunction);
};
export const listenPosts = (callbackFunction) => {
  return PostsRef.on('value', callbackFunction);
};
```

category.js

```js
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const CategoriesRef = database().ref('/categories');

export const addCategory = (label, category) => {
  return CategoriesRef.child(label).update({...category});
};

export const getCategories = () => {
  return CategoriesRef.once('value', (snapshot) =>
    snapshot.exists() ? snapshot.val() : [],
  );
};
```

assets.js

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';


const AssetsRef = database().ref('/assets');

export const getAssets = () => {
  return AssetsRef.once('value', (snapshot) =>
    snapshot.exists() ? snapshot.val() : [],
  );
};
```

I have the following dependencies installed in my app:
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.2.2",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.2.2",
"@react-native-firebase/database": "^14.11.0",
"@react-native-firebase/storage": "^14.11.0",
"firebase": "8.10.1",

I think the main problem is related to firebase since when I deleted the fetchData and the listenPostsChange functions, the app worked smoothly but without data to show.
I hope someone can help me
thanks.

edit: I just have like 15 post and 6 categories, and the assets are just 3 strings values.